# Why my .service:nth-child(1) is not is not working?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

**HTML**
for each service box i want to change background.
but `nth-child()` selector is not working.

when each  service class changed to nave with respective number its working finly.

```css
.service:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section class="about-us">
  <div class="service">
    <div class="service-header">
      <i class="fas fa-pen-nib"></i>
      <h1>Interiar</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="service-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro corporis modi alias officia quod repudiandae fugit, eveniet ipsum, doloremque facere dolores ex illo hic quidem.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="service">
    <div class="service-header">
      <i class="fas fa-pen-nib"></i>
      <h1>Interiar</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="service-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro corporis modi alias officia quod repudiandae fugit, eveniet ipsum, doloremque facere dolores ex illo hic quidem.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The code above works for me. What is the expected output?

Comment: this qusetion has no error

Comment: nth-child(1) use ```first-child```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Answer (score 0):

To change the background for each service box to red remove `:nth-child()` from the css.

```
.service {
  background-color: red;
}
```

`nth-child(#)` will get the number(#) of the element. Here 1st element with the match is selected and the style is applied.

To change the background for each try this :

```css
.service:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
}
.service:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<section class="about-us">
  <div class="service">
    <div class="service-header">
      <i class="fas fa-pen-nib"></i>
      <h1>Interiar</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="service-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro corporis modi alias officia quod repudiandae fugit, eveniet ipsum, doloremque facere dolores ex illo hic quidem.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="service">
    <div class="service-header">
      <i class="fas fa-pen-nib"></i>
      <h1>Interiar</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="service-text">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Porro corporis modi alias officia quod repudiandae fugit, eveniet ipsum, doloremque facere dolores ex illo hic quidem.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: i have more than two `div` with `service` class and i want to change color of each `dive` with class `service` with different color

Comment: i have tried this but its not working

Comment: @VinayakKhandekar To change the color for each div and there are no predefined divs with service class then you need to use javascript to append a style to each service class element with a color you store in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to remove background-color from `.service`. Background-color should be defined in the `nth-child` property.

If you want it more modular, I would recommend to use even/odd.

```css
.service {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.service:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: red;
}

.service:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="service"></div>
<div class="service"></div>
<div class="service"></div>
<div class="service"></div>
<div class="service"></div>
<div class="service"></div>
<div class="service"></div>
```

But you can also play around if you add different background-colors with for example `:nth-child(3n+3)`, which means: Every third element: 3rd, 6th, 9th, etc, will have that background-color applied.

`:nth-child(2n+2)` => 2nd, 4th, 6th...